# Scraping loop using proxies everything

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, while-loop

Hello fellow coders :)

So as part of my research project I need to scrape data out of a website.
Obviously it detects bots therefore I am trying to implement proxies on a loop I know works (getting the brands url):

The working loop:

```
brands_links= []
for country_link in country_links:
    r = requests.get(url + country_link, headers=headers)
    soup_b = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
    for link in soup_b.find_all("div", class_='designerlist cell small-6 large-4'):
        for link in link.find_all('a'):
            durl = link.get('href')
            brands_links.append(durl)
```

The loop using proxies:

```
brands_links= []
i = 0 
while i in range(0, len(country_links)):
    print(i)
    try:
        proxy_index = random.randint(0, len(proxies) - 1)
        proxy = {"http": proxies[proxy_index], "https": proxies[proxy_index]}
        r = requests.get(url + country_links[i], headers=headers, proxies=proxy, timeout=10)
        soup_b = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
        for link in soup_b.find_all("div", class_='designerlist cell small-6 large-4'):
            for link in link.find_all('a'):
                durl = link.get('href')
                brands_links.append(durl)
        
        if durl is not None :
            print("scraping happening")
            i += 1
        else: 
            continue
    
    except:
        print("proxy not working")
        proxies.remove(proxies[proxy_index]) 
    
    if i == len(country_links):
        break
    else:
        continue
```

Unfortunately it does not scrape all the links.

With the working loop only using headers I get a list of lenght 3788. With this one I only get 2387.

By inspecting the data I can see it skips some country links hence the difference in length.
I am trying to force the loop to scrape all the links with the "if" statement but it does not seem to work.

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong or got an idea which would make it scrape everything?
Thanks in advances

Comment: Any chance you could share the URL?

Comment: @PaulM. the url is: 'https://www.fragrantica.com' . Please bare in mind that to run the loop I need to scrape the country links first :)

Comment: For some reason stack overflow automatically tranfroms the link. It is preceeded by https://

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for sharing the link.

You said:

> Obviously it detects bots therefore I am trying to implement
> proxies...

What makes you think this? Here is some code I came up with, which seems to scrape all the divs, as far as I can tell:

```
def main():

    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    countries = (
        ("United States", "United+States.html"),
        ("Canada", "Canada.html"),
        ("United Kingdom", "United+Kingdom.html")
    )

    headers = {
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
    }

    for country, document in countries:
        url = f"https://www.fragrantica.com/country/{document}"

        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        response.raise_for_status()

        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
        divs = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "designerlist"})
        print(f"Number of divs in {country}: {len(divs)}")

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
Number of divs in United States: 1016
Number of divs in Canada: 40
Number of divs in United Kingdom: 308
>>>
```

Comment: Hello Paul, thank you for your quick reply! So the scraping of the brands work without any problems. The issue starts when I scrape the perfumes URLs from the brands URLs. Since there are more that 60000 perfumes, the website detects a bot after a few hundred perfumes scraped. That is the reason why I build the loop in the question. To test the proxies and move on to the next one when it is actually scraped. I hope I made my problem clear now :)

Comment: Also could you explain what is the if statement at the end for?

Comment: @IYJJ Thanks for the clarification. I'll take a look and see what I can come up with. [Here is a link to a thread which answers your question about the if-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/419185/10987432). In a nutshell, it's just a cute way of conditionally executing the main function, depending on whether or not the current module is the main program, or if it's being imported by another module.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a way to for the loop to keep the scraping until it actually scrapes the link.
Here's the updated code:

```
brands_links= []
i = 0 
while i in range(0, len(country_links)):
    print(i)
    try:
        proxy_index = random.randint(0, len(proxies) - 1)
        proxy = {"http": proxies[proxy_index], "https": proxies[proxy_index]}
        r = requests.get(url + country_links[i], headers=headers, proxies=proxy, timeout=10)
        soup_b = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
        for link in soup_b.find_all("div", class_='designerlist cell small-6 large-4'):
            for link in link.find_all('a'):
                durl = link.get('href')
                brands_links.append(durl)
    
    except:
        print("proxy not working")
        proxies.remove(proxies[proxy_index]) 
        continue 
    
    try :
        durl
    except NameError:
        print("scraping not happening")
        continue
    else: 
        print("scraping happening")
        del durl

    i += 1
    if i == len(country_links):
        break
    else:
        continue
```

So it is the last if statement which checks if the link was actually scraped.

I am not really familiar with functions. So if anyone has a way to make it simpler or more efficient I would highly appreciate. As for now I will be using @Paul M function to improve my loop or tranform it into a function.